# API shows pevious business at location

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm setting up a website using wordpress and elementor - under the elementor settings it asks for an API key to display the map. I configured the API and thought I had it all set up, but when I inserted the API key into elementor the resulting map shows a pin with the name of the business who used to occupy that building 6 months ago. When I removed the API key and just use the location - the map pin says "4" instead of the name of the business. Hovering over the pin it says "4/31 Irvine Dr" which is the address. How can I get the pin to show the name of the business?

I tried creating an API key and inserted the key into the wordpress backend.
I expected it to show the business name on the pin
It shows the previous business instead

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.